# If $X$ is a Banach space what is $X^*$?

Tags: notation, banach-spaces

I came across this notation today and I was wondering if the notation $X^*$ means that it is the dual space of $X$ where $X$ is a Banach space. I know that $^*$ is used for dual spaces of vector spaces but I do not know if the same is meant for Banach spaces without any other special properties. Thanks

Comment: If $X$ is Banach, $X^*$ consists only of the **continuous** linear functionals on $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hellen pointed out in the comments, $X^*$ consists of continuous or equivalently bounded linear functionals on $X$ with the induced norm:

$$ \lVert f \rVert = \sup_{\lVert x \rVert \le 1} |f(x)|. $$

$X^*$ is again a Banach space (i.e. complete).

Comment: So it is like a dual space?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes this is the dual space usually assigned to topological vector spaces. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Continuous_dual_space).

Comment: I never had a comprehensive explanation, but I'd say there are 4 kind of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces : finite dimensional, normed, topologic, formal. The first one has only one topology and all norms are equivalent and is self-dual, the second comes with a natural operator norm its dual being a Banach space (even if it was non-complete), the 3rd has a topologic dual with the weak-* topology, the 4th is a mess and has a thing called the algebraic dual.